# Code stops/ends after each case selected in nested switch and error C4244 conversion from double to float in c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, calculator

I have made a calculator( code below ) and it seems to run smoothly, except for 6 C4244 errors which don't seem to effect the way it runs. The only problem that I have now is that after you select any case, the program runs that part of the case and exits, but I want it to return to the main switch after it runs the case selected.How can that be done and why am i getting the errors?

```
void main(void)
{
    int c;
    printf("Enter the number of the type of operation you would like to perform:\n\n");
    printf("1.Basic Mathematical Operations\n2.Trignometric Operations\n3.Quadratic Operations\n4.Lograthimic Operations\n5.Matrix Operations\n\nNumber selected: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&c);
    switch(c)
    {
    case 1:
        int m;
        printf("\n\nEnter the number of the operation you would like to perform:\n");
        printf("1.Addition\n2.Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4.Division\n5.Exponent\n6.Square Root\n7.Inverse\n\nNumber selected: ");
        scanf_s("%d",&m);
        switch(m)
        {
        case 1:
            add();
            break;
        case 2:
            sub();
            break;
        case 3:
            mul();
            break;
        case 4:
            div();
            break;
        case 5:
            exp();
            break;
        case 6:
            sqrt();
            break;
        case 7:
            inv();
            break;
        }
        break;
}
```

One of the C4244 errors is in the following function,in the line "r=sin(a*Pi/180.0);" and the function is called in another nested switch case:

```
void sind(void)
{
  float a, r;
  printf("enter angle");
  scanf_s("%f",&a);
  r=sin(a*Pi/180.0);
  printf("The sine of %f degrees is %f.\n", a, r );
  _getch();
}
```

Comment: MVCE please, not *all* your code.

Comment: You asking for trouble with all the nested for loops with no `{}`

Comment: Please read ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks all like `C` to me.  I don't see a hint of `C++` in your code.

Comment: If you broke up that gigantic switch/case into logical functions, then you would probably be able to organize a while() loop effectively to achieve your goal.

Comment: A friend suggested using return statements. Will that work, and where will I place the return statements? I am sorry, but I am new to C programming, and still in the learning process.

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion error of double to float is most likely due to the use of 180.0 which is automatically interpreted as double. You have to add an 'f' as suffix to specify a float like this 180.0f. Also you have to pay attention to your declaration of 'Pi' which should also be a float number.

Comment: pi is also being used in 6 other functions where it gives no error. I think the error is associated with 180 like you suggested earlier, since the functions with it give error only, but 180.0f is making no difference.

Comment: The only possible reason I see then is you have only the double version of the "sin" function. I mean, the return value of the sin call is a double and it is set to a float variable.

Answer (score 0):

You asked two questions, so I don't know which one is relevant to your post.  However, I will answer the one where you are having trouble getting the code to go back to the beginning to request subsequent choices to the user.

The easiest way to accomplish the loop is to break up your code into functions.  Having switch statements that are so many lines long is not maintainable, and the logic gets all lost.

Also, the main() function returns `int`, not `void`.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int promptAndGetOperation()
{
    int op;
    cout << "Enter the number of the type of operation you would like to perform:\n\n";
    cout << "1.Basic Mathematical Operations\n2.Trignometric Operations\n3.Quadratic " 
              "Operations\n4.Lograthimic Operations\n5.Matrix Operations\n\n"
               "6. Exit\n\nNumber selected: ";
    cin >> op;
    return op;
}

void performOperation(int op)
{
   // fill this in
}   

int main(void)
{
    int operation;
    do
    {
       operation = promptAndGetOperation();
       if ( operation >= 1 && operation <= 5)
          performOperation(operation);
       else
       if ( operatiom < 1 )
         cout << "Illegal operation.  Try again\n\n";
    }
    while (operation != 6 );
}
```

This is a basic skeleton of what you should be doing.  See how simple the `main` program becomes?  The do-while loop is the main driver.